# Overwrite parent style

Tags: css, sass

I've got the following html and css

```css
.a {
  text-align: center;
  a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: $blue;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    font-weight: 700;
  }
}

.btn {
  display: block;
  padding: 1rem 2.5rem;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: $medium;
  font-weight: $bold;
  cursor: pointer;
  &-grey {
    background-color: $light-grey;
    color: $grey;
  }
  &:hover {
    background-color: $green;
    color: white;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="a">
  <a class="btn btn-grey" href="#">Link</a>
  <a href="#">Another Link</a>
</div>
```

I have styles for the `a` div that needs to affect the classless anchor tag, and at the same time I need the `a` tag with the `btn` class to have a different style. Needless to say, they both inherit the style I declared on the parent.

Is there an optimal and fully supported way to either overlook inheritence or increase specificity ?

I'm using Sass and the `btn` is styled in a different file, if I would nest it inside the parent it works as expected.

Comment: I think you might need to rephrase the question I don't really understand what you are trying to do. it might help to see an example of the sass. Are you trying to target `Link` and not `Another Link` or the other way around?

Comment: @AshleyMedway Updated the question. I'm trying to target `Another Link` and overwrite the styles applied by the parent container to all `a` tags.

Comment: What property are you trying to overwrite? The `text-align`?

Comment: @LinkinTED the text color.

Comment: Please, mark the post as solved by marking the answer as solution in order to let other users find it quick.

Answer (score 2):

There's a pseudo selector

```
:not(.class)
```

```css
.a {
    text-align: center;

    a {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: $blue;
        font-size: 1.2rem;
        font-weight: 700;
    }
}


.btn {
    display: block;
    padding: 1rem 2.5rem;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: $medium;
    font-weight: $bold;
    cursor: pointer;

    &-grey {
        background-color: $light-grey;
        color: $grey;
    }

    &:hover {
        background-color: $green;
        color: white;
    }
}
div.a > a:not(.btn){
    text-decoration: none;
    color: red;
}
div.a > a:not(.btn):hover{
    color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">
    <a class="btn" href="#">Link</a>
    <a href="#">Another Link</a>
</div>
```

**EDIT**

Added pseudo selector to show how you can set two in a row to increase specificity of the selector.